# How can I programmatically tell if an eps file has a gradient?

Tags: imagemagick, eps, imagemagick-identify

I imagine imagemagick or likewise could achieve this, but have not yet found a command to tell me.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

No. Or at least, not reliably. The [eps](/questions/tagged/eps) language doesn't have a `gradient' directive that can be quickly identified.

From [MJ Rutter's - EPS: a Programming Language](http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~mjr/eps.pdf)

> There are several ways of creating a gradient fill background:
>   Gradient Fills
>
> 1. Draw filled rectangle covering whole area, then a rectangle marginally smaller covering almost whole area and of next shade, etc.
> 2. Draw abutting filled rectangles.
> 3. Draw slightly overlapping filled rectangles.
> 4. Scale a 1D bitmap appropriately.

Authors of EPS files would leverage old-school techniques, and I wouldn't be surprised if various companies / vendors have implemented unique methods of applying gradients.

You can always render the EPS file into a raster image, than use [computer-vision](/questions/tagged/computer-vision) to determine if a gradient slop exists. See [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/3016) for an idea.